# babel with express js :avoid relative path imports

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Currently my imports like this

```
 import router from '../../app/routes'
```

Is there any way to avoid this `../../` for eg: `import router from 'app/routes'` in typescript I can do it like

```
{
  "@app/*":["app/*"]
}
```

Is anything same available in Babel??

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use [`babel-plugin-module-resolver`](https://github.com/tleunen/babel-plugin-module-resolver)

```
"plugins": [
  ["module-resolver", {
    "root": ["./src"],
    "alias": {
      "app": "./app",
    },
  }]
]
```

for instance to alias all references to "app" to be `./src/app`.